# Set margin-top according to the height of the other element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two navbar´s (one under the other). My goal is that both are fixed at the top, so I applied to both (fixed-top).

To make the other navbar fit under the other, I used a margin-top. My problem is that this margin top is not responsive, if you increase or decrease the screen size, the navbar does not fit perfectly under the other.

Is there a way to fit them correctly or calculate the necessary margin top?

[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/2TSOM6lWEM)

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white MyNavBar fixed-top" >
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2" id="dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="btn"><img src="home.svg"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto order-0">
            <a class="btn"><img src=".logo-home.svg"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dual-collapse2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2" id="dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <div class="row">
                <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" style="width: 57px;">
                     <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
                </li>
            </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white fixed-top Mytoolbar" style="margin-top: 74px;">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse22" id="dual-collapse22">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="dual-collapse22">
            <li class="nav-item folder_category">
               <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
              <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dual-collapse22">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3" id="dual-collapse22">
          <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
              <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
              <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse22" id="dual-collapse22">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
           <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
              <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link">
            </a>
            </li>           
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="toggle-third nav-link">
                <img src="ra.svg" >
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
              <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
              <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Put both navbar's in a container and use fixed-top for the container.

Comment: With the container, the width is not 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

1. Wrap both navbars in the same `div`
2. Give this `div` the `fixed-top` class
3. Remove the `fixed-top` class from both navbars
4. remove the inline css of the second `navbar` (`margin-top: 74px;`)

See below:

```css
.MyNavBar {
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 17px rgba(188, 188, 203, 0.14);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BCBCCB;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.MyNavBar img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white MyNavBar">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2" id="dual-collapse2">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="btn"><img src="home.svg"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto order-0">
      <a class="btn"><img src=".logo-home.svg"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dual-collapse2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2" id="dual-collapse2">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <div class="row">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" style="width: 57px;">
            <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white Mytoolbar">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse22" id="dual-collapse22">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="dual-collapse22">
        <li class="nav-item folder_category">
          <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
          <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto order-0">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dual-collapse22">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3" id="dual-collapse22">
        <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
          <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
          <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse22" id="dual-collapse22">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
          <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="toggle-third nav-link">
            <img src="ra.svg">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
          <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item btn-upload">
          <a class="nav-link btn">sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>

<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
<p>asdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddjioasdjasdiasjdiowjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjdhio</p>
```